# Can i add warning or error message on ios swift inbuilt methods like print(), so that if someone uses that method they can a warning message?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swift4

I just want to add a warning or error message on a inbuilt swift method print(), If someone uses print() method anywhere in my project i want to show them a compiler warning or error. (like please don't use print method, use someOther Method instead).

Is it possible ?
Please help.

Comment: you can use assert

Comment: assert will work at run time, right ?
I need a warning at compile time.

Comment: yes it will show at run time